# div with rounded forms

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a web design and there are a bit strange forms, something like this:
[image]

when the user hover on 1 section the background should change only for it:

[image]

the same for the second and third one:[image]

Hope I'm clear...

I have no idea what technology should I use in order to achieve this affect. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I think just normal divs with background images will do fine. You cant tackle this with css3

Comment: as far as I know you can't do this with regular HTML/CSS. There are some nice effects in CSS3 however : http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Comment: i know flash is considered dirty these days :)

Comment: ... and everyone's after this shiny css3 magic :)
but from what i can see the main issue here is the irregular form, which can't be used for mouseover events on dom nodes (which need to be rectangular). 
in flash you get the desired mouseover behaviour out-of-the-box though, as flash will always respect the shape of a movieclip to decide over an mouseover event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. use SVG to draw the shapes, with a fallback for older versions of IE.
2. Use background images. on normal shaped divs.

Answer (score 3):

Could use absolutely positioned pngs with image replacement on hover, then throw a rectangular div inside there

Answer (score 0):

I would go with three separate images, each with the whole background and one "selected" area - on hovering a `div` just replace the background to the one having that `div` as "selected".

Quick example for the JS code:

```
function ReplaceBg(oDiv, num) {
   oDiv.parentNode.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/background_" + num + ".png)";
}

function RestoreBg(oDiv) {
   oDiv.parentNode.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/background.png)";
}
```

And the HTML:

```html
<div style="background-image: url(images/background.png);">
   <div onmouseover="ReplaceBg(this, 1);" onmouseout="RestoreBg(this);">First</div>
   <div onmouseover="ReplaceBg(this, 2);" onmouseout="RestoreBg(this);">Second</div>
   <div onmouseover="ReplaceBg(this, 3);" onmouseout="RestoreBg(this);">Third</div>
</div>
```

Hope the idea is clear enough..

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS3 syntax `boreder-radius` and you can do this with it, but you had do the work here , I mean you had set the random pixels and look for the one which suits best. For example here it is -- http://jsfiddle.net/divinemamgai/Ld7He/

OR

Maybe you should keep the main background image as white for images `1` and `3` and for image `2` use `png`
 based background-image and change it on mouseover using `Jquery` and don't forget to keep the highest `z-index` for image `2`.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

May this help http://jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/G3VG7/